# Multiple inputs in a CNN model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, accelerometer, conv-neural-network

[Please click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHQ2o.png)I am asking this question because a lot of questions were asked assuming the input to the CNN model to be an image.
My question is -
I have a .csv file containing come accelerometer data noted over a period of 0-2 minutes.
I have another .csv file containing accelerometer data noted over a period of 0-2 minutes as well( the experiment was basically repeated)
I have another .csv file with the same experiment repeated a third time.

I want to make a model, which does some predictions over this period 0-2 minutes, however I have three different datasets that I can give as input. Do I need to merge them together, one after the other? Or is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is best to use greater dataset for training, unless it is too large or repetitive. Set aside small part of it for testing.
Hard to tell more without specific details.

Comment: Hi @Poe, thanks for responding. I have added a picture for some clarity. Suppose I have two datasets which i want to provide as input to the model. Then what can be the best approach for it?

Comment: In your case, I would encode color as one-hot variable and merge the 2 datasets.